# Lenovo g700 & Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, touchpad, bluetooth

i have few problems with this computer and ubuntu. Firstly, if i slide across my touchpad multiple times, the computer freezes. But if i use USB mouse, the problem won't occur. Secondly i can't create a Wifi hotspot using access point mode. Lastly my bluetooth is softblocked and i can't connect any devices to it.

1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth

Soft blocked: yes

Hard blocked: no

I have tried rfkill unblock all, and few other options, nothing works.

Thank you for any help,
regards

Comment: Please respect the policy of the site : one problem = one question, it seems here that have more than one problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ap-hotspot from the webupd8 repository to create an infrastracture AP instead of adhoc. I am using this on Ubuntu, but it is available for Saucy, Raring and Quantal as well.

```
$ sudo su -
# add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
# aptitude update
# aptitude install ap-hotspot
# ap-hotspot configure
# ap-hotspot start
```

There is problem with Ubuntu 13.04. It is not connecting to other HotSpot.

But you can use `ap-hostspot` instead. Read [how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access to install](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access.html) `ap-hotspot`

Comment: Your wireless card or driver does not support Access Point mode                                   
When i try to use it i get this, i don't know if my wifi card supports transmitting signal, but the computer is new and i think it should have this option..